Submit Review button pressed app stop working
I am doing the functionality for the Submit Review Button but each time I press the button the app stop function. The app is made in flutter and first I create a button Add review that opens a bottom sheet where the user can choose the stars rate 1-5 and write something and when Submit Review button is pressed the app stop working(https://imgur.com/a/18CbbJb) . Here is the code
    void _showReviewSheet(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedRating = 0;
    final reviewController = TextEditingController();

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) => Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            left: 16,
            right: 16,
            top: 16,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Write a Review',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                  return IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      index < selectedRating ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedRating = index + 1;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              TextField(
                controller: reviewController,
                maxLines: 3,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Share your experience...',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (selectedRating == 0) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Please select a rating')),
                      );
                      return;
                    }

                    try {
                      print('Attempting to submit review...'); // Debug print

                      // Create the review data
                      final reviewData = {
                        'userId': userId,
                        'rating': selectedRating,
                        'comment': reviewController.text.trim(),
                        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                      };

                      print('Review data: $reviewData'); // Debug print

                      // Get the current document
                      final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('programs')
                          .doc(workoutId);

                      // Update the document using arrayUnion
                      await docRef.update({
                        'reviews': FieldValue.arrayUnion([reviewData])
                      });

                      print('Review submitted successfully'); // Debug print

                      // Close bottom sheet and show success message
                      if (context.mounted) {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Review added successfully'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print('Error adding review: $e'); // Debug print
                      if (context.mounted) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Error adding review: $e'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Submit Review',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


It could be due to the behavior of Navigator.pop(context) and the snackbar message showing after that. When the bottom sheet is closed with Navigator.pop(context), the context of the bottom sheet is no longer valid, and any use of it after that can cause a crash.
if (context.mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
  if (context.mounted) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Review added successfully'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
});

Try this instead.
